# Dynamically bind Dropdown items Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This question may be duplicate or trivial but i can't seem to make it work.

I am using Matrial-UI in my React.js app to implement dropdown like this.

```
<Select native value={this.state.contractType} onChange={this.handleChange} input={<OutlinedInput id="contractType"/> }>
    {this.fetchContractTypes}
</Select>
```

`fetchContractTypes` gets the dropdown values from a database.

```
fetchContractTypes = async () => {
    const dropDownValues = await ProjectAPI.getDropDownValues();
    const contractValues = dropDownValues.filter(value => value.type === 'contract');
    const data = [];
    contractValues[0].value.map(val => {
        data.push(<option key={val.id} value={val.id}>{ val.name }</option>)
    });
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```

I can see the dropdown values are being fetched in the browser console window but the items are not getting binded. Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by binding?

Comment: @humanbean Populating the items.

Comment: you have to call the function `this.fetchContractTypes()`

Comment: Does this solve you issue?

Comment: @humanbean No..

Comment: move data to state of the component and update the state once you receive options,
in render function iterate through the options and render `<option />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fetch data before render and put it in component state**

I suggest you fetch the data in a useEffect hook (if you are using hooks) or componentDidMount() of you are using class based components. Then set the fetched value as sate and reference your state in the render method.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchContractTypes()
}
```

Set state in your `fetchContractTypes()`

```
fetchContractTypes = async () => {
    const dropDownValues = await ProjectAPI.getDropDownValues();
    const contractValues = dropDownValues.filter(value => value.type === 'contract');
    const data = [];
    contractValues[0].value.map(val => {
        data.push(<option key={val.id} value={val.id}>{ val.name }</option>)
    });
    this.setState({contractTypes: data});
}
```

Reference state in render

```
<Select native value={this.state.contractType} onChange={this.handleChange} input={<OutlinedInput id="contractType"/> }>
    {this.state.contractTypes}
</Select>
```

Comment: You are right. One more thing is that, I am fetching the data within an async function, which is a `Promise` and React will not take that.

Comment: Just set your state inside a `.then` on the promise and you should be ok. ```promise.then((value)=>this.setState( {contractTypes: value}))``` And then you can use a different function to filter and map your data before showing it in render